# Scalability Analysis on GPU

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, gpu, scalability

I am trying to do a scalability analysis using my Quadro FX 5800 which have 240 cores to the run time scales with number of cores which is a classic study for parallel computing.
I was wondering how does the definition of the core fit it in this ?
And how can I use it to run on different core settings say ( 8,16,32,64,128,240 cores ) ?
My test case is the simple matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scalability on the GPU should not be measured in terms of CUDA cores but in terms of SM utilization. IPC is probably the best single measure of SM utilization. When developing an algorithm you want to partition your work such that you can distribute sufficient work to all SMs such that on every cycle the warp scheduler has at least one warp eligible to issue and instruction. In general this means you have to have sufficient warps on each SM to hide instruction and memory latency and to provide a variety of instruction types to fill the execution pipeline.

If you want to test scaling across CUDA cores (meaningless) then you can launch thread blocks containing 1, 2, 3, ... 32 threads per block. Launching non-multiple of WARP_SIZE (=32) threads per thread block will result in only using a subset of the cores. These are basically wasted execution slots.

If you want to test scaling in terms of SMs you can scale you algorithm from 1 thread block to 1000s of thread blocks. In order to understand scaling you can artificially limit the thread blocks per SM by configuring the shared memory per thread block when you launch.

Re-writing matrix multiply to optimally scale in each of these directions is likely to be frustrating. Before you undertake that project I would recommend understanding how distributing a simply parallel computation such as summing from 0-100000 or calculating a factorial scales across multiple thread blocks. These algorithms are only a few lines of code and the aforementioned scaling can be tried by varying the launch configuration (GridDim, BlockDim, SharedMemoryPerBlock) and kernel 1-2 parameters  You can time the different launches using the CUDA profiler, Visual Profiler, Parallel Nsight, or CUevents.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using CUDA or OpenCL as the programming model: One simple way to restrict the utilization to `M` number of multiprocessors (SM) is to launch your kernel with an execution configuration of `M` blocks (of threads). If each SM is composed of N cores, in this way you can test scalability across N, 2N, 4N, ... cores.

For example, if the GPU has 4 SMs, each SM having 32 cores. By running kernels of 1, 2 and 4 blocks, your kernel will utilize 32, 64 and 128 cores of the GPU.

Comment: Do you mean that the number of blocks correspond to cores ?
I don't think that's right

Comment: @ashwin: That isn't correct. On the card in question, M blocks run on 8M cores for 1<M<=30, and 240 cores for M>30.

Comment: Talonmies: Isn't it true that: (A) One block is restricted to a SM (cannot be split across SMs) (B) If there are 4 blocks and 4 SMs, the global scheduler will place one block per SM?

Comment: @Ashwin: It is true. And there are 8 cores (note cores) per SM. So your statement "One simple way to restrict the utilization to M number of cores is to launch your kernel with an execution configuration of M blocks" is wrong. If you launch 1 block, it runs on 1 SM = 8 cores, 2 blocks on 2 SMs = 16 cores, 3 blocks on 3 SMs = 24 cores etc, up to the 30 SMs of this particular device are all running blocks = 240 cores.

Comment: Talonmies: My bad! I had been reading about CPU cores before answering this and mixed up the jargon :-) Please have a look at the answer now and feel free to edit it if its wrong.